# matching query does not exists - error in Django search

Tags: python, django

I have been struggling with this for a while now.I tried to implement Django search with pagination. Pagination works, but when I try to search something, I get this error:

```
Course matching query does not exist.
```

Here is the traceback: https://pastebin.com/jJp2hLUs

And code:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def pagination(request, data, num=10):
    paginator = Paginator(data, num)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        courses = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        courses = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        courses = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    index = courses.number - 1
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
    end_index = index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
    page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]

    return courses, page_range


def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        results = Course.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
    else:
        results = Course.objects.get()

    pages = pagination(request, results, num=1)

    context = {
        'courses': pages[0],
        'page_range': pages[1],
        'query': query,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)


def courses(request, slug):
    query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
               'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path('(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', views.courses, name='courses'),
    path('results/', views.search, name="search"),
]
```

Comment: You need to show your urls.py. It seems that your `courses` view is being called instead of the `search` one.

Comment: Why are you using a `Q` object for that query?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added urls  in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL "/results/" matches the pattern for `courses` so that view is getting called. You should swap the order so that Django matches against the literal string "results" first.

Also, if you're using "path" it's best to be consistent and use it throughout - Django includes a "slug" type in the new format. So:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('results/', views.search, name="search"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.courses, name='courses'),
]
```

Finally, note that your results URL is not capturing a "slug" argument, so your view shouldn't expect it and you shouldn't use it in the search query.